# Rails 3: Links that Call Actions but Don't Leave/Refresh the Current Page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way in Rails 3 to call an action (to play around with a database) without refreshing or running the action then redirecting to the current page?

I tried messing with `:remote => true` in `link_to`, but it doesn't work for me. Or maybe I misunderstood its purpose... or I'm using it incorrectly.

Comment: `:remote => true` should work. Post more code.

Comment: Oh well I tried using { } around the :action and :id and now it works!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 scenarios you normally have when calling an action from a view in Rails3:

1. Using the normal `link_to` with its variations.
2. Using `link_to` with the optional argument `:remote => true` (default is `false`)

The **first** one results in the the normal request / response cycle:

1. Call the action in the controller.
2. If there is nothing special done (`render` or `redirect`), just render the view that is related to the action. So if the action is called `do_db_stuff`, Rails3 tries  to render `do_db_stuff.html.erg` (or do_db_stuff.html.haml`) in the relevant views directory.
3. You may change that by calling explicitly `render` or `redirect` at the end of your action:

   - `render`: Renders the template you name, using the current state of the controller.
   - `redirect`: Redirect to a new action (of this or another controller), and using the relevant template to render then.

This is e.g. used when calling in the `create` action some save method, which fails, then you return to the same page by calling `render :action => "new" # doen't execute the method`

The **second** one just calls the action, and returns the result to the page. It is the responsibility of the page what to do with this. In a slightly different scenario, I have e.g. in my application something that goes like that:

1. On the left side of the view, there is a list of tasks.
2. To each task item, there is registered an on-click handler that calls `search_task` (by using JavaScript with AJAX) on the controller.
3. The controller responds to that call by sending the result of a `render :partial ...` call back.
4. The JavaScript function in the handler has registered a success function that looks like that:

   ```
   element.bind('click', function() {
       $('#left').children().removeClass('selected')
       element.addClass('selected');
       $.ajax({url: '/tasks/search_task/' + task_id, 
           async: false,
           dataType: 'html',
           success: function(data) {
               target.html(data);
           }});
   }
   ```

   (have appended the whole click-function here)
5. So the result (when successful sent) will result that the contents of `target` will be replaced with the sent HTML code.

I don't know if something similar is possible with `link_to`, perhaps there is an option.

So yes, `:remote => true` should work for you if you only want to ignore the result.

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation. You stated in your answer "it is the responsibility of the page what to do with this", and I was wondering: how do I tell the page what to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

I am using AJAX request for this:

```
<%= link_to "stock", { :controller => 'ReadItLater', :action => "stock", 
                     :qid => q.question_id } , :remote => true, :class=>'ddm' %>
```

Here is a controller code:

```
    def stock
      @user = UserData.find_by_login(session[:cuser])
      @user.stock(params)

      respond_to do |format|
          format.js { render :layout=>false }
      end
  end
```